# can I show this set is closed?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a normed vector space with norm $||\cdot||$. Suppose $S$ is a linear subspace of $X$ and $S$ is closed. Let $x\in X$. I was wondering whether the set $\{||x+s||: s\in S\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: It need not be.

Comment: I take a converging sequence $t_n$ in the set. To this sequence there corresponds $s_n$ in $S$, i.e. $t_n=||x+s_n||$. Since $t_n\rightarrow t$ and the norm is continuous then $t=||x+\lim s_n||$. Can I conclude from here that the limit of $s_n$ exists?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296354/given-a-point-x-and-a-closed-subspace-y-of-a-normed-space-must-the-distance) related question.

Comment: @DavidMitra I would go so far as to call this a duplicate of that question. Do you agree?