# $\|x+\mathcal{M}\|=0 \iff x\in \mathcal{M}$.

Tags: normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

I recently asked this question.
[Existence of x∈X such that ∥x∥=1 and ∥x+M∥=1 for a closed subspace M](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883012/existence-of-x-in-mathcalx-such-that-x-1-and-x-mathcalm-1-fo)

And people said that when $\mathcal{X}$ is normed vector space, even if $\mathcal{M}$ is closed and  $$\|x+\mathcal{M}\|=\inf_{y\in \mathcal{M}}\|x+y  \|=d$$, we cannot say that there exists $y\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\|x+y\|=d$ due to this result([Given a point $x$ and a closed subspace $Y$ of a normed space, must the distance from $x$ to $Y$ be achieved by some $y\in Y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296354/523306)).

And I started to solve a problem 5.1.12 of Folland's real analysis which says

> **5.1.12** Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a normed vector space and $\mathcal{M}$ a proper closed subspace of $\mathcal{X}$. Then $$\|x+\mathcal{M}\|=\inf_{y\in \mathcal{M}}\|x+y  \|$$   is a norm on $\mathcal{X\setminus M}$.

In order to prove it, we need to prove that $$\|x+\mathcal{M}\|=0 \iff x\in \mathcal{M}$$, which seems contradicts to the results above.

Could anyone teach me where I am thinking wrongly?

Comment: It's not (necessarily)  a contradiction - you can't guarantee $d \in M$ for arbitrary $d$ but perhaps you can for $d=0$.

Comment: @EthanBolker  Which property does make that difference?

Comment: I don't understand the queetion in your comment. The assertion you claim contradicts what you want to prove says that "sometimes: there is no $y$ in the set that minimizes the distance. But that "sometimes" may or may not be relevant for the particular case you want to prove. There is probably a proof for the case you care about.

Comment: @EthanBolker  I got your point. My question is then how to prove that the $$\|x+\mathcal{M}\|=\inf_{y\in \mathcal{M}}\|x+y\|$$ is a norm. I was searching the methods of the proofs people used and found that most of them are using that $\|x+\mathcal{M}\|=d$ then there exists $y\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\|x+y\|=d$. For example, look at this.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351781/norm-on-a-quotient-space

Comment: Additionally, if you google 'Folland solution chapter 5' and look at the solution of the problem 12, you will find they use the property.

Comment: I can't help you further with this. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x\in  \mathcal{M}$ it is clear that $\Vert x+\mathcal{M} \Vert=0$.
Now suppose $x\not \in  \mathcal{M} $, since $\mathcal{M}$ is a closed set, and assuming we are using the normed topology, there exists an open ball centered in x, that does not intersect $\mathcal{M}$ then for every  $y\in \mathcal{X}-\mathcal{B}(x)$ we have $\Vert x-y\Vert >0$.

Comment: I was so stupid.... Thank you!